# How to call bat file present inside firefox extension content directory 

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a bat file which needs to be called from javascript in firefox extension ..

I have bat file present in content/chrome directory.. 
I tried to call bat file like this ..

```
var exe = 

Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1']
          .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
exe.initWithPath("chrome://sample/content/test.bat");
exe.launch();
```

But it's not working ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the nsIProcess interface:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications#Using_nsIProcess

I've used this with batch files before successfully.

(Specifically, here: http://code.google.com/p/extensiondev/source/browse/trunk/content/extensionbuilder.js#915 although some of that code may be out of date!)

Comment: Support for nsl is removed in firefox 57. Is there any other way?